# How do I read a Table In Postgresql Using Flink

Tags: postgresql, apache-flink

I want to do some analytics using Flink on the Data in Postgresql. How and where should I give the port address,username and password. I was trying with the table source as mentioned in the link:https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/table/common.html#register-tables-in-the-catalog.

```
final static ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
final static TableSource csvSource = new CsvTableSource("localhost", port);
```

I am unable to start with actually. I went through all the documents but detailed report about this not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tables and catalog referred to the link you've shared are part of Flink's SQL support, wherein you can use SQL to express computations (queries) to be performed on data ingested into Flink. This is not about connecting Flink to a database, but rather it's about having Flink behave somewhat like a database.

To the best of my knowledge, there is no Postgres source connector for Flink. There is a JDBC table sink, but it only supports append mode (via INSERTs).

The CSVTableSource is for reading data from CSV files, which can then be processed by Flink.

If you want to operate on your data in batches, one approach you could take would be to export the data from Postgres to CSV, and then use a CSVTableSource to load it into Flink. On the other hand, if you wish to establish a streaming connection, you could connect Postgres to Kafka and then use one of Flink's Kafka connectors.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to run an update query in postgres using flink? I was doing insert query and its working fine which is as follows:

`finaloutput.map(new Writents(fhir_resource))
. output( JDBCOutputFormat.buildJDBCOutputFormat()                               .setDrivername(Utils.properties_fetch("drivername"))                     .setDBUrl(Utils.properties_fetch("dbURL"))                     .setUsername(Utils.properties_fetch("username"))                     .setPassword(Utils.properties_fetch("password"))
.setQuery(query)
.finish());`

Answer (score 1):

Reading a Postgres instance directly isn't supported as far as I know.  However, you can get realtime streaming of Postgres changes by using a [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) server and a [Debezium](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/connectors/postgresql.html) instance that replicates from Postgres to Kafka.

Debezium connects using the native Postgres replication mechanism on the DB side and emits all record inserts, updates or deletes as a message on the Kafka side.  You can then use the Kafka topic(s) as your input in Flink.